# Django extract string from [ErrorDetail(string='Test Message', code='invalid')]

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, serialization, django-rest-framework

I would like to show in my template only message that is in string variable, but I don't know how. I am using Django Rest Framework. My code:

form.html

```
<p>{{ serializer.amount.errors }}</p>
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Data, Material


class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = ('order_date', 'material', 'amount', 'delivery_number', 'employee')
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'insert_time')
    extra_kwargs = {"amount": {"error_messages": {"invalid": "Test Message"}}}
```

views.py

```
class Form(APIView):

renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = 'zulieferung/form.html'

def get(self, request):
    materials = Material.objects.distinct('material_unit_id')
    return Response({'all_materials': materials})

def post(self, request):
    materials = Material.objects.all()
    serializer = DataSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({'all_materials': materials}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response({'serializer': serializer}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And instead of ***Test Message*** in my template I have ***[ErrorDetail(string='Test Message', code='invalid')]***

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try in your template

```
{% for error in serializer.amount.errors %}
    {{ error }}
{% endofor %}
```

But I do not understand why do you use django rest_framework with HTML templates. Rest framework is used for REST APIs which is definitely not this case. For this purpose use rather `django.forms`. It really does not make sense to use REST serializer directly rendered to the HTML template.

### Links:

[Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/)

[When to use REST framework](https://www.quora.com/When-do-you-use-Django-Rest-Framework)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working. I will read about forms, I thought that drf would be better for my application. Thanks again!

Answer (score 16):

You can get the string from the `ErrorDetail` Object in this way:-

```
>>> op = ErrorDetail(string='Value must be valid JSON or key, valued pair.', code='invalid')
>>> op.title()
'Value must be valid JSON or key, valued pair.'
```

Comment: This really helped me

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> error = ErrorDetail(string='Value must be valid JSON or key, valued pair.', code='invalid')
>>> str(error)
'Value must be valid JSON or key, valued pair.'
```

Answer (score 1):

> As the serializer's errors are in a list, so you have to handle it more preciously,
> I put a very straight forward and intuitive solution to get the **string** value from the object.

```
for key, values in serializers.errors.items():
   error = [value[:] for value in values]
   print(error)
```

> Then you can get all error in a list. Though fields has multiple errors in list. so my code can extract string from ErrorDetail() objects.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing one invalid serializer data, when i haved this problem, check:

```
{"key": [ErrorDetail(string='Test Message', code='invalid')]}
```

This ErrorDetail is <class 'rest_framework.exceptions.ErrorDetail'>
[DRF class ErrorDetail](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py)
when you find attrs of this class you can check code

```
class ErrorDetail(str):
"""
A string-like object that can additionally have a code.
"""
code = None

def __new__(cls, string, code=None):
    self = super().__new__(cls, string)
    self.code = code
    return self
```

You can access to code like regular object, like this:

```
response.data['key'][0].code #'invalid'
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to access the string with the following command --> response.data['Error'][::]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error message from rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError object as follows

```
err = ErrorDetail(string='User with the given Email exists', code='invalid')
err_message = err.args[0]
```